# IE/MS Edge links in Bootstrap col-* not working on page load

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

So I have this very simple Bootstrap landing page, and everything works great in Chrome/Safari etc, however I found out today that you cannot click on some links when you use Microsoft's Edge Browser.

The page is live at [Slice Virtual Golf](http://www.slicevirtualgolf.com/)

On closer inspection, it would seem to be only the links which are inside Bootstrap `col-` parents which have trouble being clicked, and interestingly, if you change the browser window size, or open the developer tools then the links magically start being accessible.

I have had a good search, found a couple of issues similar, left a comment for a Microsoft support engineer who had suggested to fix the problem that a clean boot was required, however that seems a little excessive to me for something which looks like a bug.

If anyone knows of this issue or can take a quick look at the code then please let me know what you come up with because it's just too weird of a thing not to try and resolve.

Comment: Hmm...is it possible for you to reproduce the problem and include it in a [mcve]? Sometimes that can also help you track down the root of the issue yourself - and it's always better to have the code in your actual question, rather than on an off-site resource.

Comment: @Serlite Sure, I totally get that, usually the code is part of a much larger application I am working on. This however, is a tiny single landing page where you only need to inspect some HTML/CSS. And also, there is a distinct possibility this might be something related to the page as a whole and creating a small version might not be successful. I will put something up as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: I am an engineer on the Microsoft Edge team, and I see the issue to which you are referring. I'll investigate further, trying to establish a reduction.

Comment: @Sampson That's great. Let me know if you need other info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Internet Explorer, and Microsoft Edge. I was able to determine the cause to be the temporary application of *overflow: hidden* to the body, and the floated/positioned layout of the anchors *below the fold*. It appears as though IE/Edge determine these to be unreachable links (initially) as a result of the *overflow: hidden* styling.

I have reduced your page to the following:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 100%;">
    <head></head>
    <body style="margin: 0; height: 100%">
        <a style="float: left; position: relative; margin-top: 1000px" href="#">Link</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.body.style.overflow = "visible";
            }, 2000 );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This combination results in non-functioning *below the fold* anchors.

A bug has been filed for the Microsoft Edge team to evaluate this issue.

Track this bug: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7843412/

Comment: Nice, that's great work. So I can temporarily find a workaround if Edge Support becomes more important. Its is the Splash page of out site which makes those adjustments so I could modify or look for a different one. Lets hope it gets fixed soon enough

Comment: @SandorA If you put a version of the site back up with the loader, I can help you try to find another work-around.